# jQuery: tablesorter not working on table loaded using jquery load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm trying to use jquery tablesorter on tables that are loaded dynamically. But, while table sorter works fine in a static table, I can't get it to work in a loaded table.

I've tried calling tablesorter() after the load() and also calling it in the callback function of the load(), according to an answer to a similar question posted here. But none of them works.

This is an example of what I'm doing:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
    <!-- First table gets sorted properly -->
    <table id="firstTable">
        <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Number</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody><tr><td>John</td><td>100</td></tr><tr><td>Paul</td><td>200</td></tr></tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- Second table where the sort doesn't work -->
    <div id="secondTable"></div>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function($){
            $("#firstTable").tablesorter(); 

            $("#secondTable").load("secondtable.html", callback);

            function callback() {
                $("#secondTable").tablesorter();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body></html>
```

And also the contents of 'secondtable.html':

```
<table id="secondTable">
    <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Number</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr><td>Steve</td><td>500</td></tr><tr><td>Alice</td><td>800</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Try `$("div#secondTable table").tablesorter();` since ID's are expected to be unique.

Comment: It does work! Thank you very much for your help. For the benefit of other readers, I could only make it work by calling tablesorter() in the callback function of the load(), as shown in the code above.